# Integer nullable column in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Is it possible to have integer column nullabale in laravel?

I have table `image` where i store multiple image and get id of my `posts` `products` `website_banner` and I need them to be nullable. For example if I upload multiple image for my product not get error of my posts column have not default value!

my migrations:

```
Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('banner_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Schema::table('images', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
            $table->foreign('banner_id')->references('id')->on('banners');
        });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must call `nullable()`, like so:

```
$table->integer('banner_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, just add the `->nullable()` to your line:

```
$table->integer('website_banner')->unsigned()->nullable();
```